# Mysql Query for fetching result if corresponding table has records

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch records from one table ,if corresponding tables has record.

I am using this query .

```
SELECT `category_name`, `id` as cat_id FROM categories  WHERE (SELECT count(id)> 0 FROM `articles` where `category_id` = cat_id)  ORDER by `category_name` ASC
```

it is throwing error **unknow cat_id**

Any idea. how to do this

Thankse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inner join could do this

```
select
c.category_name,
c.id as cat_id FROM categories c
join articles a on a.category_id = c.id
order by c.category_name
```

For the performance make sure that the joining keys are indexed

I would suggest to have something as

```
alter table categories add index id_idx(id);
alter table categories add index category_name_idx(category_name);

alter table articles add index category_id_idx(category_id)
```

Comment: it will show repeat stuff. if articles table have same id more than once

Comment: add a `group by c.id` before the order by clause.

Comment: I am not sure. weather it is good for performance wise or not.